# Do-while cycle scanf reads cycles two times instead of one when reading single character

Tags: c, char, scanf

I have this code :

```
char c;
do
{
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("coucou\n");
} while (c!='q');
```

And here my result :

**Input:**

```
M
```

**Output:**

```
coucou
coucou
```

Why does it print "coucou" 2 times every time ?

Answer (score 1):

The cycle is executed 2 times because `scanf` scans 2 characters, one for `M` and another for the `\n` new line character.

You can easily solve this by adding a condition to your cycle:

```
do
{
  if(getchar() != '\n')  
    printf("coucou\n");
} while (c!='q');
```

Comment: Thanks, bu i get the same result if i replace scanf by a c=getchar() and deleting "\n"

Comment: @RobinGehan `scanf` reads from `stdin`, in your cycle, when you input a character there will always be two characters in, even if you delete it, it has no impact in `scanf` execution, with `getchar` is the same thing.

Comment: @RobinGehan you are welcome, I edited in a possible solution to your problem, don´'t forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it's a good answer to your question..